# ¿Cómo devolver una URL hateoas como parte de mi recurso?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Actualmente tengo un servicio implementado en Spring Boot como sigue (código simplificado para resaltar el problema):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/carros")
public class CarroController {
    @Autowired
    private CarroService carroService;

    @Autowired
    private CarroMapper carroMapper;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public CarroDto findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Carro carro = carroService.findById(id);
        return carroMapper.mapToCarroDto(carro);
    }
}
```

`CarroMapper` es un mapper creado usando mapstruct. Su código es:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring",
        uses={ MarcaModeloMapper.class })
public interface CarroMapper {
    @Mappings({
        //más mapeos, este es el principal que me permite generar las urls
        @Mapping(source="listaImagenCarro", target="rutasImagenes")
    })
    CarroDto mapToCarroDto(Carro carro);

    String FORMATO_URL_IMAGEN_CARRO = "/carros/%d/imagenes/%d"
    /*
        MapStruct va a invocar este método para convertir mi dto
        de imágenes de carro a una url. Esto lo hago manualmente.
        Aquí radica mi problema.
    */
    default String mapToRutaImagen(ImagenCarro imagenCarro) {
        if (imagenCarro == null) return null;
        return String.format(
                   FORMATO_URL_IMAGEN_CARRO,
                   imagenCarro.getCarro().getId(),
                   imagenCarro.getId()
               );
    }
}
```

La respuesta que obtengo al invocar el servicio es como sigue (reducida):

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "marca": { ... },
    "modelo": { ... },
    //más campos...
    //aquí el arrego de las imágenes convertidas a urls
    "imagenes": [
        "/carros/9/imagenes/1"
    ]
}
```

Lo que necesito es que el campo `imagenes` devuelva un arreglo de URLs válidas de acuerdo al servidor que estoy usando. Por ejemplo, si despliego mi aplicación en `localhost:8080` quisiera que la respuesta sea así:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "marca": { ... },
    "modelo": { ... },
    //más campos...
    "imagenes": [
        "http://localhost:8080/carros/9/imagenes/1"
    ]
}
```

He visto que este tutorial de Spring Boot explica cómo hacerlo: [Building a Hypermedia-Driven RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/). El problema es que debo cambiar el objeto de mi respuesta, cuando no quiero cambiar todo el objeto, solo un campo.

¿Cómo se puede lograr esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta con [la ayuda de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786347/1065197). Indicaré los pasos para resolver el problema.

1. Agregar la dependencia a Spring HATEOAS. Agrego la dependencia de maven (herramienta que uso):

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. En `CarroMapper`, modifiqué el código para usar los beneficios de Spring HATEOAS mediante la clase `ControllerLinkBuilder`. Aquí el código que uso y una explicación del mismo:

   ```
   public class CarroMapper {
       default String mapToRutaImagen(ImagenCarro imagenCarro) {
           if (imagenCarro == null) return null;
           /*
            - `ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo` permite armar un objeto `Link` que
              tendrá el detalle de la URL que necesito consultar. Para eso, va
              a inspeccionar la URL asociada al método de un controlador. Si
              la URL tiene parámetros, será mejor asignar los mismos en la
              invocación del método.
            - `ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn` permite indicar el controlador sobre
              el cual queremos obtener el método donde se encuentra la URL que
              queremos mapear. Por ejemplo, yo quiero mapear a la URL que apunta
              en mi método `CarroController#findById` entonces coloco dicha clase
              y mando a invocar el método. Esto NO significa que el método será
              ejecutado para obtener la url.
            - Luego, como yo solo necesito la URI (no URL) del link construido
              hasta el momento, llamo al método `toUri` y lo necesito como una
              cadena, así que invoco a `toString`.
           */
           return ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(
                       ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn(CarroController.class)
                          .descargarImagenCarro(imagenCarro.getCarro().getId(), imagenCarro.getId(), null)
                  ).toUri().toString();
       }
   }
   ```

En mi caso, el método `CarroController#descargarImagenCarro` estaba definido así:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/imagenes/{idImagenCarro}")
public void descargarImagenCarro(
        @PathVariable("id") Long idCarro,
        @PathVariable("idImagenCarro") Long idImagenCarro,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    //obtener arreglo de bytes
    //y escribirlo en la respuesta directamente
}
```

Cabe resaltar que el método `ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo` no va a funcionar si el método usado por `ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn` devuelve un `void`. Para resolver este problema, tuve que cambiar la definición de mi método `descargarImagenCarro` a como sigue:

```
@GetMapping(path={"/{id}/imagenes/{idImagenCarro}", "/{id}/imagenes/{idImagenCarro}/"})
public ResponseEntity<Void> descargarImagenCarro(
        @PathVariable("id") Long idCarro,
        @PathVariable("idImagenCarro") Long idImagenCarro,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    //obtener arreglo de bytes
    //y escribirlo en la respuesta directamente
    //por último, devolver la respuesta
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```